# Create new items in QuickBooks via C#

Tags: c#, quickbooks, qbfc

I have a C# tool that I wrote to sync orders from a DB to QB, and every step has been a giant pain.

I'm trying to create the line items that we have in our DB in QB so I can attach the invoice items correctly, but our system allows sales staff to enter custom words, so I can't just add all the possible line items to QB through the QB interface.

I have this piece of code here

```
IMsgSetRequest AddItemRequestMsgSet = sessionManager.CreateMsgSetRequest("US", 8, 0);
AddItemRequestMsgSet.Attributes.OnError = ENRqOnError.roeContinue;

IItemServiceAdd itemAddRq = AddItemRequestMsgSet.AppendItemServiceAddRq();
itemAddRq.Name.SetValue(Item);
// itemAddRq.ORSalesPurchase.

IMsgSetResponse ItemAddResponseMsgSet = sessionManager.DoRequests(AddItemRequestMsgSet);
IResponse ItemAddResponse = ItemAddResponseMsgSet.ResponseList.GetAt(0);
```

But this is throwing an error that:

> ORSalesPurchase: required field is missing

I haven't the slightest idea of what that means, and for the life of me I can't find anything about `ORSalesPurchase` or `IItemServiceAdd` elsewhere on the Internet, including their docs.

I can tell with Visual Studio's autocomplete that `itemAddRq.ORSalesPurchase` has a bunch of options, but I haven't been able to infer from that what QB is asking for.

[image: QB is the worst]

What are the required fields for adding a service item to QB?

<sub>And if someone can point me to where this is in their docs that would be extra wonderful:)</sub>

---

Stack trace:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040307):
>   ItemServiceAdd ORSalesPurchase: required field is missing End of
>   ItemServiceAdd
>
> at QBFC12Lib.IQBSessionManager.DoRequests(IMsgSetRequest request)
>   at SterlingQBExport.Form1.CheckNewInvoices(Object source,
>   ElapsedEventArgs e) in C:\Users\brian\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\SterlingQBExport\SterlingQBExport\Form1.cs:line 537

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace ? or have you set each of them and test if it works ?

Comment: @RajmondBurgaj just added it

Comment: @RajmondBurgaj I'm not sure what to "set" here for this option, there's not a `SetValue` method on `ORSalesPurchase` or its children as far as I can tell

Comment: "...and every step has been a giant pain." Every once in awhile you come across a simple example...and the gates of Heaven open and the angels rejoice!

Comment: @ChrisCatignani every day that involves dealing with QuickBooks is a sad one

Comment: I agree...Im having to create Journal Entries with IJournalEntryAdd()...and all I have to work with is the chitty example in OSR...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on an article I found while searching for `ORSalesPurchase` ...

[C# .NET Application with QuickBooks Desktop Edition](http://www.nullskull.com/a/1568/c-net-application-with-quickbooks-desktop-edition.aspx)

> This article is an introduction on how to integrate a .NET application with QuickBooks Desktop Edition using the QuickBooks Foundation Classes (QBFC) Library and C#.

... and the error message, it would seem that you are missing certain fields expected to be part of the requests `ORSalesPurchase`

Using a sample from the article I would suspect it looks something like the following

```
//Create the message set request object to hold our request
IMsgSetRequest addItemRequestMsgSet = sessionManager.CreateMsgSetRequest("US", 8, 0);
addItemRequestMsgSet.Attributes.OnError = ENRqOnError.roeContinue;

IItemServiceAdd itemServiceAddRq = addItemRequestMsgSet.AppendItemServiceAddRq();
itemServiceAddRq.Name.SetValue(Item.Name);
itemServiceAddRq.ORSalesPurchase.SalesOrPurchase.Desc.SetValue(Item.Description);
itemServiceAddRq.ORSalesPurchase.SalesOrPurchase.ORPrice.Price.SetValue(Item.Price);
itemServiceAddRq.ORSalesPurchase.SalesOrPurchase.AccountRef.FullName.SetValue("Some custom service description here");

//...
```

Now there was more which seems to infer that the fields set differ based on the items already having a quickbooks id where it was set using

```
itemServiceModRq.ListID.SetValue(Item.QuickBooksID);
```

Now, I am not entirely certain what the required fields are at this point, but this should be a good starting point to check if providing the fields above helps.

Comment: You are absolutely the best, that snippet and that article were exactly the thing I was looking for

Comment: I'll award that bounty when SO lets me, 19 hours :)